# Quando usar o constexpr em C++?

Tags: c++, constantes

Vejo por aí a palavra-chave `constexpr` (principalmente em `if`s e constantes) muitas vezes, já li a documentação da Microsoft e pesquisei na internet e mesmo assim não entendi muito a função dela e quando usar, queria uma explicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu começaria lendo a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) que é considerada quase como oficial por todos. Sem dominar a documentação não considere que entende o mecanismo, especialmente em C++ isso é fundamental, esta é uma linguagem que funcionar e estar certo costuma ter uma distância muito grande.

Dando uma lida lá acho que dá para perceber que uma resposta aqui ficaria longa e de certa forma reproduziria a documentação encontrada lá. Se fizer um resumo muito grande de fato não está respondendo a pergunta, dar um motivo e ignorar todos os outros, ficar sem falar em todas restrições acaba não ajudando tanto. Eu resolvi responder alguma coisa porque a resposta aceita atualmente responde menos do que isso.

De fato `constexpr` foi criada para deixar claro para o compilador que ele aquilo deveria ser resolvido em tempo de compilação e portanto aquela expressão pode ser otimizada de várias formas e até eliminada do executável.

Ela difere de `const` que não estabelece uma expressão constante e sim que há alguns constância possivelmente transitória naquilo. Um dos usos é declarar um identificador que será usado como um valor fixo. Na prática esse uso é igual ao de `constexpr` e de fato se não fosse o legado esse palavra chave seria preferida, e `const` seria usada em outros contextos que nem vou falar aqui porque não é o foco.

Isto é perfeitamente válido:

```
constexpr int x = 10;
constexpr int y = x + 5;
```

O primeiro dava para fazer com `const`, mas o segundo não. Note que só pode fazer entre constantes, não pode usar variável.

De fato um dos usos mais proeminentes é com `if` e é uma forma mais robusta, poderosa e flexível do `#if` que se constava usar antes no pré processador que era legado do C. Então você diz que quer que a condição ali deve ser resolvida pelo compilador e a ação a ser usada na compilação é o que está dentro do bloco do `if` ou do `else` conforme o resultado durante a compilação. Isso dá um poder muito grande de programação eficiente escolhendo só o que interessa para aquele caso. Isso é muito poderoso especialmente com *templates* já que o objetivo deles é compilar alguma coisa de acordo com o código sendo consumido. Antes tinha que fazer malabarismos para ese código ser compilado condicionalmente e agora é fácil e tem uma sintaxe simples e intuitiva.

Exemplo:

```
template <typename T>
auto get_value(T t) {
    if constexpr (is_pointer_v<T>)
        return *t;
    else
        return t;
}
```

Este código retornará um valor ou um ponteiro para um valor dependendo do tipo de `T` ser um ponteiro ou não. Note que a chamada da função é que definirá como será compilado. Não haverá custo de processamento, haverá duas versões (se for usado das duas formas) da função e será chamada aquele que servir em cada caso. Então o `if` escolheu o que compilar de acordo com o resto do código (a chamada da função no caso).

Fazendo a função ser constante podemos ter o resultado se passarmos um literal sem custo de processamento na execução:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int fibonacci() {
    if constexpr (N >= 2)
        return fibonacci<N - 1>() + fibonacci<N - 2>();
    else
        return N;
}
```

Essa função será executada pelo compilador, achará o resultado e ele será usado na geração do executável.

Note que não pode passar uma variável já que o valor dela não é conhecido em tempo de execução, até por exigência do gabarito.

Se não está entendendo nada é porque falta aprender sobre *templates*. Mas não é o único local onde podemos usar `constrexpr`.

Mas podemos usar em situações mais simples:

```
constexpr bool is_even(int num) { return num % 2 == 0; }
```

Isso será resolvido em tempo de compilação se passar uma constante, mas será executado em tempo de execução se passar um valor que não pode ser determinado pelo compilador.

Mas pode usar em mais contextos, por exemplo:

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    public:
        constexpr Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
        constexpr int get_x() { return x; }
        constexpr int get_y() { return y; }
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/ConstexprExamples.cpp).

Note que até o construtor é constante, e já que tudo consegue entregar de forma constante o objeto não é criado durante a execução, o compilador consegue criá-lo na compilação, desde que, claro, tenha dados constantes em compilação sendo passados para o construtor. Então mesmo um objeto complexo pode virar um valor completamente estático, o que antes não dava para fazer.

Uma [leitura mais completa pode ser vista no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117121/221800), e não é a única resposta boa lá.

Answer (score 3):

As funções `constexpr` permitem retornar apenas uma constante e correm to tempo da compilação. Quando declaramos uma variável `const` a função é avaliada diretamente para o mesmo tipo e melhora a legibilidade.